# SQL to detect if one column contains another column

Tags: sql, db2

I try to query as following:

```
   VOUCHER   TYPE    RESULT
   vchr1     REV     CONTAINS REV
   vchr1     REV     CONTAINS REV
   vchr1     COR     CONTAINS REV
   vchr2     COR     NOT CONTAINS REV
   vchr2     COR     NOT CONTAINS REV
```

I need to detect if voucher contains REV and give flag on row level. I tried OVER PARTITION but with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression and `EXISTS`:

```
select t.*,
  case when exists (select 1 from tablename where voucher = t.voucher and type = 'REV') 
       then 'CONTAINS REV' 
       else 'NOT CONTAINS REV' 
   end result
from tablename t
```

Comment: Thank you, but this would not give me desired result. It would be only on row level, however I need flag that way all vouchers if condition is true at least in one of voucher's row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with SUM() OVER()

```
select
  VOUCHER,
  TYPE,
  CASE SUM(CASE TYPE WHEN 'REV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY VOUCHER)
    when 0 then 'NOT CONTAINS REV' else 'CONTAINS REV' end 
from tablename
```

Comment: Looks elegant and logically but for some reason query does not understand equal sign in SUM part.  (unexpected character).

Comment: SELECT.......  SUM(ABS(A.AMTDLR_REP)/2) over (partition by A.VOUCHER_NBR) AS VOUCHER_AMOUNT, 
     (CASE SUM(A.MAJOR='320') OVER(PARTITION BY A.VOUCHER_NBR) when 0 then 'NOT CONTAINS REV' else 'CONTAINS REV' end) AS FLAG  FROM......   ERROR:  An unexpected token "=" was found following "AS * AT OPTION YEAR YEARS MONTH MONTHS DAY DAYS HOUR HOURS".  Expected tokens may include:  "{2}"

Comment: @MichalPalko just made an edit, which platform and version of db2 are you using ?

Comment: Still the same error. In my pc 10.5, unfortunately i dont know what server. Interesting is, that it throws me the same error even if I state simple TYPE = 'REV' AS FLAG - I would expect true or false.

Comment: Does VALUES CHAR(1 = 1) return TRUE? I think you can't use BOOLEAN type in queries befor V11.1, I think you'd better use @forpas version with exists

Comment: You are right, does return error. Thank you anyway.